# Extracting values without looping in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Lets say we need to extract values from range of `(0..999_999_999)`. We need the **sum** of all numbers that returns true for our conditional statement. For example, the ones that have the sequence of "123" digits at the end of their numbers.

What would be the fastest way to get this sum without looping?

Edit: The conditional statement could be any, such as n.to_s.chars.map{|d| d = d.to_i}.inject(:+) % 12345 == 0 where n is the number within the range.

Edit2: Here is the code that I have trouble with:

```
def find_all(n, k)
    arr = []
    lower_limit = ("1" + "0" * (k - 1)).to_i
    upper_limit = ("9" * k).to_i  
    while lower_limit <= upper_limit
      if lower_limit.to_s.chars == lower_limit.to_s.chars.sort && lower_limit.to_s.chars.map{|v| v = v.to_i}.inject(:+) == n
        arr << lower_limit
      end
      lower_limit += 1
    end
    arr.empty? ? [] : [arr.size, arr.min, arr.max]
end
```

where `n` is the sum of all digits and `k` is the # of digits in number.

My code should run on the server in less than 12000 ms with very huge numbers of `k` several times with different `(n,k)`. Even though my code works, its algorithm is too slow, looping will not result in success.

Comment: You'd have to use some [combinatorics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics) if you want to avoid the basic, bruteforce approach. Count the `123??????` numbers, then count the `?123?????`, .... Beware though, you'd have to take care not to count the same number twice (e.g. `123123???`).

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve? Are you looking for a solution to the specific example given, or are you looking for a general solution that works for any "conditional statement"?

Comment: @Eric Duminil lets say its just n[-1] == 3 && n[-2] == 2 && n[-3] == 1

Comment: If you don't want to loop, take the opposite path: generate the values within the wanted range if your conditional statement allows you to "jump" from one valid case to the next. For instance: if condition is multiples of 3, you can easily go from one number to the next, thus skipping unwanted values.

Comment: @yoones good hint, but I have already tried it and it fails because the loop is still gigantic.

Comment: @Jordan works with any conditional statement, conditional statement should be dynamic

Comment: I'm not a mathematician, but I would guess that if a general solution exists, it will be extraordinarily complex. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @Jordan I added Edit2

Comment: You still haven't said why you want to do this. What's the practical purpose of your `find_all` method? What program is it a part of?

Comment: @Jordan It is like a test "create single function, pass it, it should be below 12000 ms if you run it several times". I needed make this function (which I already did - it works the way it should be) that runs much faster than my current algorithm. I have problems with my algorithm, but I don't know where to start because I am not so pro. :-)

Comment: You probably should have asked about that in the first place. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378 I agree with Cary, though—I doubt a general solution without iteration exists.

Answer (score 2):

The range is

```
r = 0..10**9-1

r.size
  #=> 1_000_000_000 (10**9)
```

For any given last three digits, this range contains `10**6` numbers ending in those three digits. Suppose those last three digits were `000`. Then the sum of those numbers would be the sum of the numbers in the range `0..10**6-1` multiplied by `10**3`:

```
s = (10**3) * (0 + 10**6-1)*(10**6)/2
  #=> 499999500000000
```

If the last three digits of each of the `10**6` numbers in this sum were `123`, rather than `000`, `123` would be added to each of those numbers. Therefore, the sum of the numbers ending `123` is

```
s + 123 * (10**6) 
  #=> 499999746000000
```

Comment: This is true for this particular example, but this is hard-coded. I would like to see a solution with a code (without the loop) where we can change the conditional statement and new sum would still be true.

Comment: Let's say the sum of all values of n that are true for  n.to_s.chars.map{|d| d = d.to_i}.inject(:+) % 12345 == 0 in the range of (0..999_999_999) in the shortest amount of time to calculate.

Comment: Mikhail, do you have some reason to believe that what you want to do is possible? I do not think it is. If it were, the author of the algorithm would be a shoo-in for the [Fields Medal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fields_Medal). To prove that it is not possible one needs to find just one example of a "condition" (in your parlance) that is known to require enumeration of the elements of the given array. I'll think about that. In the meantime, all we can do is address specific "conditions", such as the two you have stated. As for #2, I don't think there is a shortcut.

Comment: Sweveland I added Edit2